# WP Site Network htaccess redirect to https

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I use wordpress with a Site Network. Since I wanna use different kinda themes on the same domain it's necessary. To make this work I needed to change my htaccess file into what WP ordered me to. But then my redirection to https didn't work anymore.

I have the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I wanna add a redirection to https:// w w w. for any access to the website.

Anything I do, in the end one of the former rules aren't working anymore. And afterwards the Wordpress Network Sites don't work anymore.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep redirection rule before your your WP rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Also **don't forget to change permalink setting in WP to use https for your blog/site**